# Kubernetes how to deploy a pod created by configuration file?

Tags: kubernetes

I create a pod by configuration file with a volume and privileged security.

How can I deploy this pod?

I try to deploy with kubectl run or deployment configuration file. it's created a new pod without my volume and security privileged.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Could you share your config files?

Comment: Also share the output of `kubectl logs <pod-name>`, `kubectl get pods`, `kubectl get deployments`

Comment: `Volume` you mean with `pv` and `pvc`? Can you paste `kubectl get pvc`, `kubectl get pv` and describe both with `kubectl describe pvc <PVC>` outputs along with `kubectl logs <pod_name>`

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands to create and verify

This will create the pod

```
   # kubectl create -f abc-pod.yml
```

This will list the running pods

```
   # kubectl get pods
```

This will show the details of that pod

```
   # kubectl describe pod <pod_name>
```

This will show the logs of pods

```
   # kubectl logs pod_name container_name
```